# Why do I get Blazor error "Content Type not supported" in sample template project?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I created a Blazor WebAssebly (hosted) project from the project template in Visual Studio 2019.

And on the Fetch page I get this error.

I have followed some Blazor examples before and never got this.
Not sure what has changed.

Has anyone seen this error and been able to solve?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out you have to set the server project to the start project.
Mine was set to the client project.